# Problem reseting a form on client side with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, clientscript

I'm trying to reset my form using javascript on client side. The code looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function Reset() {
            TextBox1.text = "";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Reset()" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This of course isn't working, I get the error that Button1 is undefinded. I tried looking control's name within browser (by viewing page source) and using that instead of its ID but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the value using getElementById

```
var mybutton= document.getElementById('Button1');
mybutton.value = ""
```

Comment: The error "Button1 is undefined" is gone, but text remains the same, it's not cleared.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for your javascript code. It's a standard anyway.

After you reference jQuery, you may rewrite your JavaScript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function resetForm() {
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").val("");
    }
</script>
```

If you still do not want to use jQuery, then you need to access your element using its client ID like following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function resetForm() {
        document.getElemenyById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").value = "";
    }
</script>
```

Also, as @Jon pointed out, you need to either rename your `OnClientClick` value to `resetForm()` or rename your JavaScript function.

Comment: One Question, what are those odd characters and why won't it work when I remove 'em?

Comment: What odd characters? You mean <% %> these ones? This is a placeholder: the server will insert the value (`TextBox1.ClientID`) there in the response

Comment: Thanks, Is there any place I can read more on this? I mean placeholder and stuff (not jQuery) or is it jQuery?

Comment: That's a tough question for me. It appears that these characters are ASP tags, and their history starts in 1998. You can read about them here: http://www.georgehernandez.com/h/xComputers/ASP/ASPTags.asp

Comment: Basically, these tags enclose the 'server-run' area on your ASPX page. Everything inside <% %> is run on the server, and everything else is transmitted to the client's browser

Comment: Also, see this link: http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx